# How to represent states for an 8 Puzzle in a graph

Tags: algorithm, search, graph, a-star

I am trying to solve the 8 puzzle using `A*` Search for an assignment. I will be given an initial state and a goal state that I have to use to reach using the `A*` algorithm to reach the optimal path. My approach is to take the initial state as a list, then generate its successor states that can be generated based on the ways I can move the blank square(represented by 0). Then for each of the successor states I can calculate the heuristic, the Manhattan distance which I can use as the priority for a priority queue.

For example, if my initial state is `[1,2,3,0,4,5,6,7,8]: 0` , the child states would be `[0,2,3,1,4,5,6,7,8]: x`, `[1,2,3,4,0,6,7,8] : x` and `[1,2,3,6,4,5,0,7,8]: x`. I don't know how to represent this as a graph, choose the lowest priority state and then expand that.

I am not sure where to go from here. How do I add the parent state and successor to a graph so I can do `A*`?

Comment: Often with search algorithms, we don't store an explicit graph in memory. Instead, we implement the algorithm with recursion and the graph is implicit in the recursive calls. Is there a specific reason you need to do store a graph here?

Answer (score 0):

Current position is start node of graph. Then you could use a standard for yourself. Two nodes in graph are adjacent if they are reachable from each others. The label of your graph is a string consist of current numbers in your list.

for example the initial state is

```
initial = [ [ 1, 2, 3 ],
            [ 5, 6, 0 ],
            [ 7, 8, 4 ] ]
```

and final state is

```
final = [ [ 1, 2, 3 ],
          [ 4, 5, 6 ],
          [ 7, 8, 0 ] ]
```

Choose whom structure you are convince with.

Also, `A*` is a proper algorithm to solve n-puzzle.
[Solving 8-Puzzle using `A*` Algorithm.](https://blog.goodaudience.com/solving-8-puzzle-using-a-algorithm-7b509c331288)

[8 puzzle Problem using Branch And Bound](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/8-puzzle-problem-using-branch-and-bound/)

[8 puzzle problem](https://medium.com/@dpthegrey/8-puzzle-problem-2ec7d832b6db)

Answer (score 0):

In order to build a graph, you need a function that, given a state, will find all the states that are "one move away" from it.

When you implement that A* algorithm, though, the *only* thing you would use that graph for is finding all the states that are "one move away" from the state you're currently processing.

Don't bother building a graph. Just use the function.